# Factoring cubic polynomial over R

Tags: polynomials, roots, factoring

$z^3-7z^2+14z-7=0$

I tried simplifying it to $z^3-7(z-1)^2=0$, but I don't think i can proceed from there. It sort of looked like geometric progression but it is not that either, and I don't see any other approach here. Apparently roots are $4\cos^2(\frac{\pi}{14})$, $4\cos^2(\frac{3\pi}{14})$,$4\cos^2(\frac{9\pi}{14})$, but I don't know how to get them.

Thanks for help.

Comment: You won't find the roots without Cardano's formulas or similar. Are you sure about the coefficients ?

Comment: It seems like there is a typo somewhere since the roots of this equation are irrational according to [WolframAplha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+z%5E3-7z%5E2%2B14z-7%3D0).

Comment: Ye, its correct, I just checked the book and there are solutions, but not the method to get them, I will edit the post.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Not sure if you got a notification, but the OP updated the questions with the solutions, which are all in terms of $\cos^2 \dfrac {n \pi}{14}$. Do you know of a way to solve polynomials and get this kind of answer? I remember a problem where you could find the values for stuff like $\cos^2 \dfrac {\pi}{5}$ by multiplying different roots of unity somehow, but I don't remember how.

Comment: @ovi: this is a casus irreductibilis. The trick is to transform the polynomial by a linear transformation of the unknown, to the form $4x^3-3x=c$ (depress and rescale). This is as technical as Cardano.

Comment: @YvesDaoust it has cyclic Galois group, and a simple transformation takes it to the sort of cubic that Gauss's technique creates, see http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/cox_galois_Gaussian_periods.pdf  for method, and the Reuschle book I displayed for hundreds of examples.

Comment: @ovi PARI/GP is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and comes WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY WHATSOEVER.

Type ? for help, \q to quit.
Type ?12 for how to get moral (and possibly technical) support.

parisize = 4000000, prPARI/GP is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and comes WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY WHATSOEVER.

Type ? for help, \q to quit.
Type ?12 for how to get  technical support.

parisize = 4000000, 
? polgalois( x^3 - 7 * x^2 + 14 * x - 7)
%1 = [3, 1, 1, "A3"]

? polgalois( x^3 - 7 * x^2 + 14 * x - 7)
%1 = [3, 1, 1, "A3"]

Comment: ? ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @Ovi  see my answer, all this is possible because the discriminant of the cubic is a square. Gauss initiated a method for creating polynomials with roots that are prescribed combinations of certain roots of unity; this is one of the easiest examples

Comment: @WillJagy Ah okay thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $z=aw+b$. The equation turns to

$$a^3w^3+(3ba^2-7a^2)w^2+(3ab^2-14ab+14a)w+b^3-7b^2+14b-7=0.$$

Now, cancel the quadratic coefficient. This is achieved by $3b=7$, and

$$a^3w^3-\frac73aw+\frac7{27}=0.$$

Next, ensure that the ratio of the cubic coefficient over the linear one is $-\dfrac43$. This is achieved by

$$a=\frac{\sqrt{28}}3,$$

and

$$\frac{28}9\frac{\sqrt{28}}3w^3-\frac73\frac{\sqrt{28}}3w+\frac7{27}=0$$ or

$$4w^3-3w=-\frac1{\sqrt{28}}.$$

Finally, setting

$$w=\cos\theta,$$

$$4\cos^3\theta-3\cos\theta=\cos 3\theta=-\frac1{\sqrt{28}}$$ gives you the roots.

Answer (score 2):

The roots of $$ x^3 + x^2 - 2 x - 1 $$
are
$$ 2 \cos \frac{2 \pi}{7} \; , \; \; 2 \cos \frac{4 \pi}{7} \; , \; \;2 \cos \frac{8 \pi}{7} \; . \; \; $$
This is pretty easy if we take $\omega $ a 7th root of unity, then take $x = \omega + \frac{1}{\omega}$ and calculate $ x^3 + x^2 - 2 x - 1 $ while demanding $\omega^6 + \omega^5 + \omega^4 + \omega^3 + \omega^2 + \omega + 1=0$

if we then take $x = 2 - z,$ we find
$$ -(x^3 + x^2 - 2 x - 1) = z^3 - 7 z^2 + 14 z - 7 $$

The image below comes from the book by [REUSCHLE](https://books.google.com/books?id=wt7lgfeYqMQC&pg=PR1&lpg=PR1&dq=reuschle%20%20tafeln%20complexer%20primzahlen&source=bl&ots=VGZFPrfUBn&sig=MlQ667PqXaQ9rAvLWkG3_F1rwsk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiIwtSvm9TQAhUJ-2MKHXJIA_kQ6AEIODAE#v=onepage&q=reuschle%20%20tafeln%20complexer%20primzahlen&f=false) 
[image]